# Oracle APEX multiple region have different widths

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page that contains a total of three regions, each filled with a small number of charts.

Ever since the 21.2 upgrade the second and third region on my page are much more narrow that the first one. The first one (as were all three before the update) uses the entire screen width while the second and third one only use about 1/2 of the page (the third one is even a tiny bit wider than the second one). Column spans are set to automatic on all three regions.

They are all static region filled with 3 charts (same charts in each region) if that helps.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem and how may I get all three regions to use the full width of the screen again?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] including the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: Which Apex version is the "origin"? I had similar problem, where application was created in Apex 3.2 and all charts were narrow in Apex 20.2. What did I do? I created new regions from scratch (re-used queries, of course). Didn't find a way to "set something up" to make it work properly.